# Angular Router (Routing) - Cancel navigation to different route (url)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a component that should be destroyed each time the changes (for example, each time the user click to go back on history), but before the destruction of the component, I want to show a message asking if the user wants to leave without saving the changes.

The user can select the "no" answer, which the app should stop the navigation in this case. If the user selects the "yes" answer, the navigation should continue.

My question is, how can I do that?

Follows an example:

```
export class ListConfigurationsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   ...
   constructor(
        ...
        private router: Router) {

        router.events.subscribe((val) => {
            //Cancel the option here
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `CanDeactivate` guard - https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Comment: @user2216584 I believe it is not what he is looking for, since route guard is for an entire component.

Answer (score 4):

try this using **restoredState** property, it's defined when the navigation is triggered by a **popstate** event otherwise it's null, check [this](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart)

```
router.events.pipe(
  filter(( event: NavigationEvent ) => {
        return( event instanceof NavigationStart );
       })
).subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
   if (event.restoredState ) {
      // display you confirmation modal
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for CanDeactivate Guard. Check this article, it describes how to make generic CanDeactivate strategy:
https://medium.com/@tobias.ljungstrom/how-to-use-a-custom-dialogue-with-the-candeactivate-route-guard-in-angular-385616470b6a

Answer (score 0):

One version could be that you don't use the [routerLink] in your template. Use the (click) handler instead to call your function which checks if the user should be redirected.

In your html

```
(click) = "checkDialog()";
```

If so in your ts just use

```
this.router.navigate(['/next-page']);
```

in your condition

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to check for the `navigationTrigger` property on the `NavigationEvent` and check the previous state ID in the `restoredState` property as

```
if(event instanceof NavigationStart && event.navigationTrigger == "popstate" && event.restoredState)
```

Stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-check-navigation-back-fron-through-browser